# HTML5 website loads in chrome and safari but does not load in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am creating a website for a NGO, which is actually a blog on www.blogger.com
(http://youngkidsofafrica.blogspot.com/)

I used the free HTML5 template on wix.com and copied that code into the blogger (classic template) HMTL.

The site loads fine on chrome and safari but does not load at all on IE (tested on 8,9 and 10)
On IE it just loads a blank page.

I really like this template and want to use it for a the website/blog.

Can someone please help me fix this IE related issue?

Comment: You can use Developer Tools in IE. You can open with F12 after that you will see any errors or warnings in page. If you can share that errors, we can help easily.

Comment: Info warning:
HTML1200: blogspot.com is on the Internet Explorer 9 Compatibility View List ('C:\Users\Varun\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml'). 
youngkidsofafrica.blogspot.com

Errors:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'load': object is null or undefined 
1912144495-csitail.js, line 3 character 629

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
youngkidsofafrica.blogspot.com, line 1 character 1

Comment: Try getting the latest version of the codes you are using. Maybe it has been fixed in a newer version.

Comment: It is the latest code. What is puzzling is that if I load the version of the site hosted on wix server (http://varungt.wix.com/childrenofafrica) then it works fine on all browser. Its only when I copy the code into the blogger template, it won't load in IE but will load in chrome and safari.